# Updating Database from iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, database, ipad, core-data

Hi I am  newbie to iOS programming,

I am building an iOS app to display a catalogue(Product name, Item No, Discription, and Image) of the products. After the user installs the app on the iOS device there may be updates happening to the product list. The user will not be able to modify any data in the database.

Can some one give me an idea of what kind Database i would require to use (SQL lite, Json or Coredata) and how i can let the update happen. Should I update just the new / modified records or update the complete database each time.

From some examples of apps i have seen from the appstore the app downloads the entire (latest version) of the database the first time the app is loaded.

Thanks in advance to all the friends out there in the community. your suggestions, codes, examples and any reference materials and links will be of great help.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Apple's recommended framework is Core Data. Especially if you have a lot of data, it's probably worth familiarizing yourself with it.
2. Direct SQLite programming can have its advantages, but unless you have a compelling reason to pursue it (and I don't see anything suggesting this in your question), stick with Core Data. If you do decide to use SQLite, consider using the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) Objective-C wrapper for SQLite.
3. If you're dealing with a trivial amount of data (e.g. a dozen records), Core Data is probably overkill and you could just use a property list (plist). For example, if you have downloaded your JSON into a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, you can then just do `writeToFile` to save it, and `dictionaryWithContentsOFFile` or `arrayWithContentsOfFile` to read it back at a future date.
4. JSON is generally considered more of a mechanism for exchanging data with a server. I wouldn't be inclined to store data locally in JSON format (though you could). I'd use a plist instead.
5. By the way, it's generally not advised to store the images themselves in your CoreData/SQLite database. If you have larger files, for performance reasons, we often store them in the iOS [File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12) (and save some reference to the file name in the database).
6. You mention that you have seen apps that download the entire (latest version) of a database. A more sophisticated implementation (critical with larger databases) would entail downloading updates (edits, deletions, insertions) rather than the full database. For a small database, if you can get away with the solution you propose (and it certainly makes it easier), but as your app becomes more sophisticated, you will want to consider more elegant server integration.

Comment: Hi Rob though the question is closed as being too basic and a chance for debate. i greatly appreciate your guidance. I think i will go on with SQL / FMDB for now as the customer may port the applications at later stage to other platforms like android and windows Phone. yes certainly it needs server integration as they need to send notifications with promotional products. if any more doubts may i contact you ?

Comment: Very good. FMDB will help immensely if you're doing SQLite. If you have additional questions, I'd suggest you post a new question here on S.O. and because it will undoubtedly be more specific, less open-ended and abstract, it's less likely to be closed ;). If you don't get responses and it's related to SQLite, feel free to put a comment here with a link to the new question.